# design query in editor (left outer join)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Hi how do i build left outer join or right outer join using sql server 
**design query in editor**  feature (i'm using sql server2005)

Thank you,
Nagu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to join the columns, click the column you want to join on in the first table and drag it to the column you want to join on in the second table. Right click on the join that is formed and check the box "Select all rows from table xxxx"